# render() is called repeatedly when state is set

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display data from an API. After I get the data I am setting state to data from API. When I do that, the render() is called repeatedly.

I just started learning react. Please help.

```
export class Table extends Component{
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        data : []
    }
}
render(){
    const pa = this.state.data.map(function(dt){
        console.log(dt);
        return <div><p>dt.name</p><p>{dt.email}</p></div>
    })
    this.getData = ()=>{
        axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then((res)=>{
            console.log(res.data);
            this.setState({data: res.data}); //causes render() to be called repeatedly
        });
    }
    this.getData();
    return(
        <div>
            {pa} //does not work
        </div>
        );
}
```

}

Comment: Because it's going into infinite loop (render -> api call -> setState -> render->....), instead of making api call inside render do that inside `componentDidMount` lifecycle method. Refer [Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

Comment: @MayankShukla ok..i did that. but i still dont see the `pa`. What's wrong

Comment: because you forgot to use return inside map callback function, use this `return <p>{dt.name}</p>` or write it like this: `this.state.data.map(dt=> <p>{dt.name}</p>)`

Comment: @MayankShukla thanks. write as answer and i will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> render() to be called repeatedly, Why?

Because its going into **infinite loop**:

```
render -> api call -> setState -> render (repeat)
```

> {pa} //does not work, Why?

Because you forgot to use return inside map callback function.

**Solution**:

Instead of making api call inside render method do that inside **[componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)** lifecycle method, And use return inside map callback function.

Write it like this:

```
export class Table extends Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            data : []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then((res)=>{
            console.log(res.data);
            this.setState({data: res.data});
        });
    }

    render(){
        const pa = this.state.data.map((dt,i) => <p key={i}>{dt.name}</p>)

        return(
            <div>
                {pa} 
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Note**: Assign unique key to each element creating inside loop.

Comment: how do i return multiple elements like `<p>` in map. I tried to return a `div` but it didn't work.

Comment: you need to use `{}` around the dynamic value use this: `<div key={i}><p>{dt.name}</p><p>{dt.email}</p></div>`

Comment: I forgot to add it in the question. when i  tried it I included a `{}` but it didn't work.

Comment: can you explain more what exactly is failing, are you getting any error?

Comment: when i do a single element `<p>{dt.name}</p>` it works but when i do `return <div><p>{dt.name}</p><p>{dt.email}</p></div>` i see white screen. there's no error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158071/discussion-between-abhi-and-mayank-shukla).

Answer (score 1):

You should fix a couple of things (in my opinion).

First, the data fetching should be done at the `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount` hooks (as you prefer). In that way the render method will be called once instead of doing that loop.

Second, remove the data fetching from your component, and pass that functionality through a prop. In that way your component will be more testable and easy to understand. The from some other hooks you can the method like this: `this.props.fetchData()`.